# How one approaches for defining containers for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

First of all, I have extensive experience on Relational DBs but very beginner level knowledge of Document DB. I'm exploring MongoDB but my question is in general to Document DB.

AFA I know (I may be wrong), A Document DB is consisting of containers and containers contain same of different object structures. These object structures are defined such a way that filters and information can be applied in most optimum way. For ex. A is written by Authors. So object of Book will contain list of authors also. This way searching can be made faster and performance can be gained.

**What is my problem?**
I'm creating an application (yet haven't started as I'm confused here). It's relational DB is something like this....

[image]

The problem is I'm not able to design the Document DB structure for this requirement.

Please somebody help my in designing such database or can give me idea on **"What approach one should select while designing such database?"**

Comment: When you use a document database, entity-relationship diagrams are usually not a good guide.

Comment: @Philipp, True, But Since I'm suppose to give best explanation for my data to the reader of this question, I have to include this. (I know ER has nothing to do with DocumentDB)

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to answering the following questions:

1. What are your most common access patterns? It is helpful to think of your API methods, or top 5-10 queries to decide how to organize.
2. What are your transactional needs? Which of these entity types occur together in transactions and queries?
3. How often do they change? Should you embed or reference?

If you could include these details, we can help with more targeted suggestions. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/documentdb-modeling-data/ is also worth a read if you haven't already.

The main difference between DocumentDB and relational databases/MongoDB is that collections are more like shards/partitions and not tables.